# Getting text to show up on an I2C LCD

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd

I am new to electronics, and trying to get my 1602 LCD to work with an I2C adapter.
I got my backlight to work, but I can't get text to show.
This is my current code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
    lcd.init();
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
    lcd.print("HELLO");
}

void loop() {
    lcd.backlight();
    delay(2000);
    lcd.noBacklight();
    delay(2000);
}
```

I checked for the I2C address with the [scanner](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner) and it is 0x27.

I Googled a bit and came past [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=369998.0) post where someone posted this:

> Simple test
>
> Apply +5v / GND to LCD - display - and than apply background LED power ( sometime marked A/K) to the LCD   module.
>
> No other connections ( data etc.) are necessary for this power up test.
>
> You should  be able to discern ALL chatterers fields, but connecting contrast pot will make it easier.
>
> It MAY not be totally visible but the module will initialize ( internally) on  power up and ALL characters fields should show.
>
> Of course by now you know you need basically three "power" connections to the LCD - LCD itself, contrast and backlight.
>
> Sure looks as the main LCD power is missing - hence no intelligent data can be processed / displayed.

I did this test aswell and came to [these results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suxTo.jpg):

- When providing 5V to the backlight, it shows up bright.
- When providing 5V to both the backlight and the LCD itself the backlight gets darker but nothing else shows up.

I then accidentally put the I2C adapter upside down, but that did give me the text blocks.

How could I get the text to show? What am I currently doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor point, have you tried trimming the pot? I suspect that this sets the contrast, and I forgot this and I had a blank display.
Yours Simon M.

Answer (score 0):

Your I2C Adapter turns serial data into parallel output to the LCD pins. 
Are you sure this is done to the pins you expect ?

Especially if you mix *any* I2C adapter to *any* 16 pin LCD module, you should check which signals you put where ...

If required, there are LiquidCrystal_I2C constructors where you can specify the LCD pins, if the default won't fit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I believe I have the right mix of I2C adapter and LCD module but I'm not entirely sure. I bought [this LCD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/new-1pcs-LCD1602-LCD-1602-yellow-screen-with-backlight-LCD-display-1602A-5v/2036230453.html) and [this I2C adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-1602-2004-LCD-Adapter-Plate-IIC-I2C-Interface-lcd1602-I2C-LCD-Adapter-For-arduino/32249588810.html). Is there any way to find out? Also, the library I am using (it's by Frank de Brabander) doesn't seem to have the constructors you are talking about.