# Why isn't my I2C LCD Display is not displaying any letter?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd

The LCD that I bought is not working and I don't know why! When I upload the code, the display just lights up but it does not show a thing! Any help?

My LCD Model: 1602A with I2C (16x2) [Like this one here](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hb1c08d6f055f4be2bb12e1ac68d4de8dF/LCD-Module-1602-Blue-Yellow-Green-Screen-IIC-I2C-LCD1602-5V-Adapter-Plate-1602A-Display-Module.jpg_q50.jpg)

Address: 0x27 (Checked using I2C Scanning Code)

The code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2); // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(); // initialize the lcd
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(1,0);
  lcd.print("hello everyone");
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("I am Giga Blitz");
}

void loop() {

}
```

Schematic:
[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oshMf.jpg)

Comment: What is the size of your display? Is it 16x2? Also the LCD address (0x27) could be different for other displays. Can you post what display you're using?

Comment: I have updated the question as you requested and as you can see, it matches the code.

Comment: Read the datasheet for the LCD part.  It likely requires some time to perform certain functions.  Unless your library satisfies these requirements, it won't work.

Comment: I read the datasheet and used the code that was given with it. Still, no dice. But it seems that the backlight works. The only problem is that it is not printing any letter or word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting text to show up on an I2C LCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049023/getting-text-to-show-up-on-an-i2c-lcd)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using i2c, then slowly turn the blue screw in the i2c with a screw driver with the lcd program on.I hope it displays as you turn the screw.This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are using `lcd.begin` instead of `lcd.init()`;

Here is a guide: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Oniichan_is_ded/lcd-i2c-tutorial-664e5a

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(1,0);
  lcd.print("hello everyone");
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("I am Giga Blitz");
}


void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

- Make sure it's getting 5V (3.3V lit it up but letters were extremely faint)
- Could be a faulty LCD (I had a faulty I2C that lit up but no display)

Given that there's so much cheap stuff out there, definitely worth getting a few backup parts just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Use LCD I2C Address **0x3F**

OR

/* Detect I2C Address by using following code */

```
#include <Wire.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
  }
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println ("I2C Address Scanning in Progress...");
  byte count = 0;
  Wire.begin();
  for (byte i = 8; i < 120; i++)
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission (i);
    if (Wire.endTransmission () == 0)
    {
      Serial.print ("Found address: ");
      Serial.print (i, DEC);
      Serial.print (" (0x");
      Serial.print (i, HEX);
      Serial.println (")");
      count++;
      delay (1);
    }
  }
  Serial.println ("Detected");
  Serial.print ("Found ");
  Serial.print (count, DEC);
  Serial.println (" device(s).");
}
void loop() {}
```